# Quiz que muda de seção dependendo da resposta

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Estou desenvolvendo um quiz com [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), que tem que funcionar da seguinte forma, tem a **pergunta** e **feedback da resposta**, mas depois vou para outra seção onde tem uma **história** e somente depois vem **outra pergunta**.

Minha dúvida é o seguinte entre uma pergunta e outra consigo colocar um seção com um texto? Estou fazendo as questões com array, vou mostrar um exemplo de como está até agora.

```js
var questao1 = {
  questao: '<span>1.</span> Assinale a alternativa correta”',
  alternativas: ['a) Dependente; B.', 'b) Independente; B', 'c) Independente; T.'],
  correta: 2
};
var questao2 = {
  questao: '<span>2.</span> Quais são os sitomas mais comuns da doença meningocócica?',
  alternativas: ['a) Febre, mal-estar geral, dores musculares, vômitos, diarreia e dor de cabeça.', 'b) Mal-estar,diarreia, vômitos, calafrio, dor nos braços e nas pernas.', 'c) Dor de cabeça, nauseas e vômitos, intolerancia a luz e ruidos, manchas amarelas na pele.'],
  correta: 0
};

var questoes = [questao1, questao2];


// Váriaveis globais
var tags;
var tagsClass = '';
var liTagsid = [];
var alternativaCorreta = 0;
var quizPage = 1;
var index = 0;
var questaoAtual = questoes[index];
var questaoAnterior;
var indexAnterior = 0;
var ulTag = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var botao = document.getElementById('responder');
var tituloQuestao = document.getElementById('questao');
var selecionada = 'selected';

function showQuestions() {
  if (index != 0) {
    // cria o botão de responder nas próximas páginas
    ulTag.innerHTML = '';
    botao.innerHTML = 'Responder';
    botao.className = 'responder btn';
    botao.id = 'responder';
    document.getElementById('numeroQuiz').innerHTML = quizPage;
  }

  //Mostra o resultado no final da página
  if (index == (questoes.length)) {
    ulTag.innerHTML = '';
    // document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = '';
    // showResults();

    var url = window.location.href;
    var absoluto = url.split("/")[url.split("/").length - 1];
    // alert(absoluto);
    if (absoluto == 'tela03.html') {
      window.location.href = 'tela04.html';
    } else if (absoluto == 'tela05.html') {
      window.location.href = 'tela06.html';
    } else if (absoluto == 'tela07.html') {
      window.location.href = 'tela08.html';
    } else if (absoluto == 'tela09.html') {
      window.location.href = 'tela10.html';
    }
    return
  }

  tituloQuestao.innerHTML = questaoAtual.questao;
  console.log(questaoAtual.questao);

  // gera as alternativas
  for (var i = 0; i < questaoAtual.alternativas.length; i++) {
    var newAlt = document.createElement('li');
    newAlt.id = 'alt' + (i + 1);
    newAlt.className = "notSelected";
    var textAlt = document.createTextNode(questaoAtual.alternativas[i]);
    newAlt.appendChild(textAlt);
    var addNewAltHere = document.getElementById('alternativa');
    addNewAltHere.appendChild(newAlt);
    console.log(questaoAtual.alternativas[i]);
  }
  var $liTags = $('.notSelected').click(function(list) {
    list.preventDefault();
    $liTags.removeClass(selecionada);
    $(this).addClass(selecionada);
    for (var i = 0; i < questaoAtual.alternativas.length; i++) {
      // console.log(liTagsid[i]);
      if ($liTags[i].className == "notSelected selected") {
        //armazena a alternativa
        tags = $liTags[i].id;
        // tagsClass = $LiTags.className;
        console.log(tags);
        tagsClassName = $liTags[i];
      }
    }
  });
  botao.onclick = function() {
    checkAnswer()
  };
}

showQuestions();

function checkAnswer() {
  var selectedItem = document.getElementById(tags);

  // Caso não tenha escolhido alguma alternativa
  if (selectedItem == undefined) {
    alert("Por favor selecione uma alternativa.")
    return
  } else {
    var userAns = selectedItem.innerHTML;
  }
  // muda o background de acordo com a escolha
  if (userAns == questaoAtual.alternativas[questaoAtual.correta]) {
    console.log("Acertou: " + userAns);
    $('#modalAcertou').modal();
    selectedItem.className = 'correta';
    alternativaCorreta++;
    console.log(alternativaCorreta);
    $('.notSelected').addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    console.log("Errou a alternativa correta é : " + questaoAtual.alternativas[questaoAtual.correta]);
    $('#modalErrou').modal();
    return
    selectedItem.className = 'wrong';
    ulTag.getElementsByTagName('li')[questaoAtual.correta].className = 'correta';
    console.log(questaoAtual.alternativas[questaoAtual.correta]);
  }

  // Cria o botão para a próxima pergunta após responder certo
  botao.innerHTML = 'Próxima Pergunta';
  botao.className = 'next btn';
  botao.id = 'next';
  questaoAnterior = questaoAtual;
  quizPage++;
  index++;
  questaoAtual = questoes[index];

  botao.onclick = function() {
    showQuestions()
  };
  return
}
```

```css
#fundo-externo {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* para que não tenha rolagem se a imagem de fundo for maior que a tela */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /* criamos um contexto para posicionamento */
}

#fundo {
  position: fixed;
  /* posição fixa para que a possível rolagem da tela não revele espaços em branco */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#fundo img {
  width: 100%;
  /* com isso imagem ocupará toda a largura da tela. Se colocarmos height: 100% também, a imagem irá distorcer */
  position: absolute;
}

#pagina-quiz {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#pagina-quiz p,
#pagina-quiz li,
.wrapper {
  color: #6d6d6d;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#pagina-quiz li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ecedee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ecedee;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*#pagina-quiz li:hover{
    background: #ECEEF0;
}*/

#question p span {
  color: #898655;
}

#pagina-quiz .selected,
.selected:hover {
  background: #FFDEAD;
}

#pagina-quiz .correta {
  /*background: #bec8a3;*/
  background: #00ff0080;
  color: white;
}

#pagina-quiz .wrong,
.wrong:hover {
  background: #d49274;
  color: white;
}

.button {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 55px;
}


/*.submit:hover, .submit:active, .submit:focus {
    background: #43A047;
}*/

.responder {
  background: #fff;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.next {
  background: #fa994a;
  min-width: 120px;
  color: #fff;
}

.next:hover,
.next:active,
.next:focus {
  background: #e38a42;
}

.restart {
  background-color:
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  border: 0px solid #000;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.modal-content {
  border-radius: 10px;
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgb(23, 116, 15);
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

#modalErrou .modal-content {
  background: #e60000;
}

.modal-content h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#pagina-quiz .modal-content .modal-body p {
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#pagina-quiz .modal-content span {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<main id="bkgTelas">
  <div id="pagina-quiz">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalAcertou" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAcertouTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h1>Parabéns</h1>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>A resposta está correta.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalErrou" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalErrouTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h1>Atenção!</h1>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Você selecionou a resposta errada.</p>
              <p>Tente novamente.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="wrapper" id="pages">
            <span id="numeroQuiz">1</span><span>/20</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="quiz-questions" id="display-area">
            <p id="questao"></p>
            <ul id="alternativa"></ul>
            <div id="quiz-resultados" style="text-align: center;">
              <button type="button" name="button" class="responder btn" id="responder">Confirmar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Veja se é isso que procura: [Aqui](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-shannon-ys7uh?file=/index.html)

Eu adicionei as alterações que você precisa:

- Eu adicionei mais uma propriedade ao objeto da questão chamado `texto`.

Em cada declaração de objeto você agora pode incluir o texto explicativo que gostaria que mostrasse após a questão.

- Criei as funções `showText(texto)` e `showQuestionLayer()`

Essas funções apenas controlam a exibição da sua questão no html, a `showText` além disso recebe o texto que gostaria que fosse exibido por parâmetro.

- Criei uma nova `div` no seu código html

Essa `div` permite que o conteúdo esteja disponível para ser mostrado quando a pergunta for respondida, esse foi o trecho de código que inseri:

```html
<div class="container" id="texto" style="display: none">
   <div id="conteudo_texto" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
   <button
     type="button"
     name="button"
     class="next btn"
     onclick="showQuestionLayer()"
   >
     Próxima Pergunta
   </button>
 </div>
```

Com essas alterações aparentemente seu problema está resolvido.

PS.: Há formas melhores de escrever o seu código, eu apenas segui seu padrão, porém aconselho estudar um pouco mais de como funciona o jQuery e adicionar os eventos a partir do `jQuery.ready()` isso fará seu código ficar mais legível e dentro das convenções do jQuery. Apenas uma dica.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar as propriedades de visibility.
Como por exemplo:

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";
```